# Big–O for sequence with multiple indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, sequence-of-function

Let's say we have a sequence $X_{n}(k)$, where $n$ and $k$ are $1, 2\ldots$ Next, let's fix $k$ and assume that there exists function $g$
$$
X_{n}(k) \leq k^{3}g(n)
$$
with $g$ some strictly positive monotone decreasing function of $n.$

Therefore, for a fixed $k$ we can say that
$$
X_{n} = \mathcal{O}(g(n))
$$
as $n\to\infty,$ where $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$ means Big–O notation.

Does this meant then that

$$
X_{n} = \mathcal{O}(k^{3} g(n))
$$
as $n, k \to\infty$?

Comment: Can you recall the definition of big-$O$ notation? I think that will point the way. 

Also, I think it's good practice to keep the argument $(k)$ every time you write $X_n$, since its asymptotics depend on $k$. And, finally, the way I would write the second equation is with a subscript $k$ under the big $O$, i.e. $X_n(k) = \mathcal{O}_k(g(n))$, to say that the property of being big-$O$ of $g(n)$ depends on having a fixed $k$.

Comment: I think there is no standard definition for something like $f(n,k) = O(k^3 n^2)$ as $n,k \to \infty$.  When you write such a thing, you should explain what you mean.